# How do you iterate through selected cells in datagrid for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid where the user can select multiple cells of a single column in the grid, I want to iterate through the selected cells and retrieve the value of the first column of the selected cells' row, but I'm already stuck in the first step of the foreach loop. I did this before with datagridview in WinForms but it seems WPF is different.

```
foreach (DataGridCell cell in AppraiseeDataGrid.SelectedCells)//It says it cant convert type datagridcellinfo to datagricell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGrid.SelectedCells` returns an `DataGridCellInfo` in WPF:

```
foreach (DataGridCellInfo cell in AppraiseeDataGrid.SelectedCells)
{
    DataGridColumn column = cell.Column;
    object dataRowItem = cell.Item;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much i spent an hour trying to find a simple solution and this did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through all of it's items and determine if the cell is selected, check this code:

```
foreach (DataGridCell cell in AppraiseeDataGrid.Items)
        {
            if (cell.IsSelected == true)
            {
                // Type your code here
            }
        }
```

Comment: Its giving me an error that it cant convert datarowview to datagridcell

Answer (score 0):

```
string firstSelectedCellText = GetCellText(DataGrid.SelectedCells.First());

 private string GetCellText(DataGridCellInfo currentcellInfo)
        {
            var currentCell = GetDataGridCell(currentcellInfo);
            if (currentCell == null) return string.Empty;
            int itemIndex = DataGrid.Items.IndexOf(currentcellInfo.Item);
            DataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(DataGrid.Items[itemIndex], currentcellInfo.Column);
            if (currentCell.Content is TextBox textBox)
            {
                return textBox.Text;
            }
            if (currentCell.Content is TextBlock textBlock)
            {
                return textBlock.Text;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
  private DataGridCell GetDataGridCell(DataGridCellInfo cellInfo)
        {
            var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
            if (cellContent != null)
                return (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;

            return null;
        }
```